# unable to see image using pygame.image.load()

Tags: python, pygame

I am unable to see the image when I start the program. I have a folder named "game" and "mygame.py" file with a "background.png" all in it. I have tried using the the PATH "/game/background.png" instead of "background.png" but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

my code:

```
import pygame , sys 

pygame.init()

#screen start
def screen():
    screen = [1024,768]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen,0,32)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Testing Caption")
    background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))


    while True:
      screen.blit(background, (0,0))
      #keyboard commands
      for event in pygame.event.get():
          if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
              pygame.quit()   


screen()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the flip/update call:

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

  #keyboard commands
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          pygame.quit()

  screen.blit(background, (0,0))

  pygame.display.flip()

  clock.tick(40)  # keep program running at given FPS
```

Every blit occurs in a internal buffer, you need to call flip or update once per frame to update the real screen.

Comment: I replaced your while section of my code with yours and I have screen () followed by screen.flip() on the next line. But I still don't see the picture. I have to shake my drag my program left to right... and only THEN the picture appears on 0,0 coordinates on top left side of the screen. Is this normal? :/ Thanks again for your prior help.

Comment: Hi, keep in mind `flip()` must occur inside the loop no after `screen()`. Also, perhaps you need to add a clock, otherwise your program is always at 100% cpu. I edited the answer inclunding the clock.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge you can make this work one of two ways.

You can use an absolute path to the file, such as:

```
"C:\path_to_game_folder\game\background.png"
```

or you can use a relative path. To do this add the following code to your program:

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
backgroundFile = os.path.join(dir, "background.png")
```

and change:

```
pygame.image.load("background.png")
```

to

```
pygame.image.load(backgroundFile)
```

I suggest using relative paths whenever possible it keeps the code portable as well as makes it easier to maintain and distribute.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Using pygame its important to use "`pygame.display.update()`" inside `while True:` screen.flip doesn't work with pygame to refresh or update the screen. Thanks to the users who responded earlier though.

Full Code:

```
import pygame , sys

pygame.init()

#screen start
def screen():
    width , height = 1280,768
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Testing Caption")
    background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()

        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        pygame.display.update()


screen()
```

Comment: It was my mistake. The post should have been `pygame.display.flip()` instead of `screen.flip()`. I corrected my post for future references.